# youtubeSignupRequired when Uploading Video via Youtube Data API

Tags: google-oauth, youtube-data-api

i'm trying to upload a video via Youtube Data API, but I always get a `youtubeSignupRequired` error.

I found on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors?hl=en that `youtubeSignupRequired`, may mean that the user has a Google Account but does not have a YouTube channel.

That's my case, I've no YouTube channel for this Google Account, but I'm am admin of another [Youtube channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lozEo.png) (orange icon) which i can even see (under switch account) when logged in on youtube.com

I've created an empty channel now ("Testkanal"), but still don't see correct channel as an option on [Oauth2 consent screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v67DD.png)

Any ideas how it fix that, so I can uload to this channel?
Thx a lot!

Comment: Could you precise from where (YouTube data API v3 documentation website, software...) you got to the OAuth2 content screen ? "I've created an empty channel now ("Testkanal"), but still don't see correct channel as an option on Oauth2 consent screen" on your screen we see "Testkanal" so you can select it but then the response from the API is like you haven't selected "Testkanal" but your original account ?

Comment: hi @BenjaminLoison!
I'm using a console application which opens a browser window for Oauth2 consent screen.
I'm missing the account with the orange icon "Be...." ("testkanal" works fine)

Comment: seems you need to be owner of a YT channel, not just an admin?!

Comment: Maybe I'm not aware of the admin feature sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked using the owner's account.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer to help future SO users understand how you managed to solve your question?

Comment: @DanielJ it's not possible to use a google account that is just admin, but not owner of the channel. you need to use the account of the owner!

Comment: @ascebit how do I make sure I am using my Youtube owner account? I already have created a crendtials file. Can you share the code?